# Flickering of the pages, only data is being fetched, no complex logic. What can cause the flickering? Everytime i open the page it happens

Tags: reactjs, fetch, components

Flickering of the pages, only data is being fetched, no complex logic. What can cause the flickering? Everytime I open the page it happens. My data is fetched in these components they don't do anything else. I tried everything different fetch methods, loading animations, setTimeout but it makes it worse from UX point of view.

Here is a video of it: https://screenrec.com/share/xXmfehCI1B

enter link description here

This is my PersonaList component:

```
 import "./PersonalList.css";
import "../ErrorPage/ErrorPage.css";

import React, { useLayoutEffect, useState,useEffect,useContext,ReactMapboxGl } from 'react';

import RecipePersonalModel from "../Recipe/RecipePersonalModel/RecipePersonalModel";
import { AuthContext } from "../../contexts/AuthContext";
import * as userService from '../../services/userService';
import ErrorPage from '../../components/ErrorPage/ErrorPage';
import { debounce } from 'lodash';

const PersonalList = () => {


    const [recipes,setRecipes] = useState([]);
    const {user} = useContext(AuthContext);
    

        useLayoutEffect(() => {
          
          
            userService.ownRecipes(user._id)
            .then(recipeResult => {
                setRecipes(recipeResult);
            });
          
            
        }, []);
    



    return (
        <div>
            <h1>Your Recipes</h1>
            <section className="secper">

                {/* {
                   recipes.length > 0
                        ? 
                        <>
                        
                        {recipes.map(x => <RecipePersonalModel key ={x._id} recipe={x}/>)}
                        </>

                        : <div className="errorpaper">
                                <h1>No recipes found.</h1>
                                <ErrorPage/>
                          </div>
                        
                } */}
                
                {recipes.map(x => <RecipePersonalModel key ={x._id} recipe={x}/>)}
                
            </section>
        </div>
       
    );
}

export default PersonalList;
```

The Favourites component:

```
    import "./Favourites.css";

import React, { useLayoutEffect, useState ,useEffect,useContext} from 'react';

import RecipeFavourite from "../Recipe/RecipeFavourite/RecipeFavourite";
import * as userService from '../../services/userService';
import { AuthContext } from "../../contexts/AuthContext";
import ErrorPage from "../ErrorPage/ErrorPage";


function Favourites() {


    const [favourites,setFavourites] = useState([]);
    const {user} = useContext(AuthContext);
    const count = favourites.length;

    useLayoutEffect(() => {

       
            userService.yourFavourites(user._id)
            .then(result => {
                setFavourites(result);
            })
     

    },[]);

    useLayoutEffect(() => {
        window.scrollTo(0, 0)
    });



    return (
        <div>
            <h1 className = "h1m">Your Favourite Recipes</h1>

            <section className="secfav">
          
                {/* {
                   favourites.length > 0
                        ? <>
                            {favourites.map(x => <RecipeFavourite key ={x._id} recipe={x} />)}
                          </>
                        : <div className="errorpaper">
                             <h1>No recipes found.</h1>
                             <ErrorPage/>
                          </div> 
                } */}
               
               {favourites.map(x => <RecipeFavourite key ={x._id} recipe={x} />)}
            
            </section>
        </div>
    );
}

export default Favourites;
```

The SharedRecipes Component:

```
import { Link, NavLink, useNavigate, useParams } from 'react-router-dom';
import React, { useContext, useEffect, useLayoutEffect, useState } from 'react';

import RecipePersonalModel from "../Recipe/RecipeModel/RecipeModel";
import RecipeFavourite from "../Recipe/RecipeFavourite/RecipeFavourite";

import * as userService from "../../services/userService";
import RecipeShared from '../Recipe/RecipeShared/RecipeShared';
import { AuthContext } from '../../contexts/AuthContext';
import ErrorPage from '../ErrorPage/ErrorPage';


const SharedRecipes = () => {
    

    const [recipes,setRecipes] = useState([]);
    const [recipe,setRecipe] = useState([]);
    // const [favourites,setFavourites] = useState([]);
    const {recipeId} = useParams();
    const {user} = useContext(AuthContext);
   


    const recipesd = async () => {
        let reciperes =   await userService.getOne(recipeId);

        console.log(reciperes);
        setRecipe(reciperes);
    };


    useEffect(() => { recipesd(recipe); },[]);

    
    const [recipessh,setRecipessh] = useState([]);
    
    useLayoutEffect(() => {
       
        
            userService.getAll()
            .then(result => {
                setRecipessh(result);
            })
        

  },[]);


    
    // const recipesd = async () => {
    //     let reciperes =   await userService.getOne(recipeId);

    //     console.log(reciperes);
    //     setFavourite(reciperes);
    // };

    // useEffect(() => { recipesd(favourite); },[]);

    // const favouriter = (e) => {
    //     e.preventDefault();
        
    //     setFavourites(...favourites,favourite);
    //     console.log(favourite);
    // }


    const history = useNavigate();


    useLayoutEffect(() => {
        window.scrollTo(0, 0)
    });

    const publicall = recipe.publicp=="yes";


    return (
        <div>
           <h1>Shared Recipes</h1>
           <section className="sec4">

                {/* {
                   recipessh.length > 0
                        ? <>
                            {recipessh.filter(x=>x._ownerId!=user._id && x.publicp.toLowerCase()=="yes").map(x => <RecipeShared key ={x._id} recipe={x} />)}
                          </>
                        : <div className="errorpaper">
                             <h1>No recipes found.</h1>
                             
                           </div> 
                }
                */}

               {recipessh.map(x=> <RecipeShared key={x._id} recipe={x} />)}
               
              
               {/* {recipessh.filter(x=>x._ownerId!=user._id && x.publicp.toLowerCase()=="yes").map(x => <RecipeShared key ={x._id} recipe={x} />)} */}

               {/* that works

               {recipessh.filter(x=>x._ownerId!=user._id).map(x => <RecipeShared key ={x._id} recipe={x} />)} */}


    </section>
        </div>
    );
}

export default SharedRecipes;
```

Comment: "Flickering" could mean a variety of things.  A very likely candidate is that the page styling may not be handling the changing data in a way that you would like.  Can you provide a runnable [mcve] (if not here, at least at something like Code Sandbox) to demonstrate?

Comment: I added a video, tell me if you can't see it.It looks like the data fetches too slow and i see only the header and the footer first.

Comment: If it's just taking a moment to fetch data, what styling is in place to handle this?  For example, if data is being fetched then you might have a "loading spinner" shown to the user.  The header and footer could be static on the top and bottom of the viewport.  What you're describing isn't really a "flicker", it's just the UX not being styled to handle all use cases.

Comment: I don't know how to style it.I am new to react JS and css. Any suggestions to that, i stopped the flickering of one page by putting the fetching inside the app main component, but for the other ones it seems like they have a problem with prop drilling and doesn't work with them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're observing is simply the state changing.  The page just isn't styled to handle state changes in a way that conveys to the user that "data is loading".

Add a loading "spinner".  This could be graphical, or for demonstration purposes here even just text.  The main point here is that it just needs to be conditionally displayed.

For example, note where you have this:

```
userService.ownRecipes(user._id)
  .then(recipeResult => {
    setRecipes(recipeResult);
  });
```

And in the UI you have this:

```
{favourites.map(x => <RecipeFavourite key ={x._id} recipe={x} />)}
```

So what does the user see when `favourites` is an empty array?  *Nothing.*  Instead, show the user something.

From commented-out code, it already appears that you showed the user "No recipes found", but this wasn't ideal because then it misinforms the user.  Because there *are* recipes, they just haven't loaded yet.  So separate the concepts of "loading" from "no recipes".

Add another state value to indicate loading:

```
const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(false);
```

And update it in the service operation:

```
setIsLoading(true);
userService.ownRecipes(user._id)
  .then(recipeResult => {
    setRecipes(recipeResult);
    setIsLoading(false);
  });
```

Then in your UI you can now tell the difference between three states:

- Currently loading
- Loaded, no data present
- Loaded, data present

Account for those states in your UI:

```
{
  isLoading ?
    <div>Loading recipes...</div> :
  favourites.length === 0 ?
    <div>No recipes found!</div> :
    favourites.map(x => <RecipeFavourite key ={x._id} recipe={x} />)
}
```

From there it's just a matter of styling those three distinct page states however you like.  You can replace the `<div>` elements here with animated images (the term "loading spinner" can help you find some online), better styling, etc.

Overall the point is just that the component needs to be able to handle all three states for a complete user experience.